Select first column for multiple occurrences of second column and a condition from third column
I have a table which looks like this
Individual_ID   Household_ID    AccountType
-------------------------------------------
101             HH_101          CHK
102             HH_101          SAV
103             HH_101          CHK
104             HH_102          CHK
105             HH_103          SAV
106             HH_104          SAV
107             HH_104          CHK
108             HH_105          SAV
109             HH_105          SAV
110             HH_106          CHK
111             HH_106          SAV

I want to select all the Individual_ID's which have the same Household_ID and a Checking Account (CHK = Checking and SAV = Savings).
I am trying the below query
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Individual_ID, Household_ID, AccountType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Household_ID ORDER BY Individual_ID ASC) AS Acct_Per_Household
    FROM
        [Test].[dbo].[AccountsInfo]
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE Acct_Per_Household > 1 AND AccountType = 'CHK'

But the above query is excluding Individual_ID = 101 because of the way it is written. So what I am trying to achieve is if a Household_ID is occurring more than once, then select all Individual_ID who have a checking account(CHK). So the output should look like below.
Individual_ID   Household_ID    AccountType
-------------------------------------------
101             HH_101          CHK
103             HH_101          CHK
107             HH_104          CHK
110             HH_106          CHK

I know this can be done through windowing functions, but I am not sure about which function to use to achieve the goal.

Please add the expected result. And what do you mean by "same Household_ID"? Same as what? In your sample data, all individual id's have a household_id that appear for another individual id, except for individual id 104 and 105? So do you want to list all except those two? What has this to do with the AccountType?

WHERE Acct_Per_Household > 1 is failing for Individual_ID=101  (you could have checked this, like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/5iT-q7vX )

@JonasMetzler - Added the expected output.

@Luuk - By failing I meant that my output should have Individual_ID 101. Please take a look at the expected output and things might be clearer.

The question is still unclear. As I understand it, you want to do following: https://dbfiddle.uk/W75avwpz. In this answer, a different logic has been applied. The logic in the answer fails if the condition in the EXISTS subquery is wrong. My solution might fail for other cases. Please explain more detailed your use cases.

Or the other way: https://dbfiddle.uk/xRPmVIEV

@VivekKumarSingh - You mention both checking and savings accounts in your criteria, but only include checking accounts in your results. If a household has more than one checking account, but no saving account, should those checking accounts still be included? See this db<>fiddle which includes extra test data for this case and applies all of the proposed solutions posted so far.  By the way, your original code might have just needed COUNT(*) instead of ROW_NUMBER(). That variation is also included in the fiddle.

Try this:


WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 
      Household_ID as hid, count(Individual_ID) as num_indivs
  FROM AccountsInfo
  WHERE 
   AccountType = 'CHK'
  GROUP BY Household_ID
  HAVING count(Individual_ID) > 1
)
SELECT Individual_ID, HouseHold_ID, AccountType
FROM
   AccountsInfo ai INNER JOIN cte ON ai.Household_ID = cte.hid
WHERE 
   AccountType = 'CHK'
ORDER BY 
   Individual_ID

Basically the cte figures out which households have more than one individual per household that have checking accounts.
The JOIN gets you the details about those households.
You can probably use an IN with a subquery as well, but a JOIN is often considered faster. I would profile both and see which performs better for your use case.
Your use of ROW_ID and PARTITION may lead to a solution, but I think this more classic solution may be easier to understand.

This works great. Thank you for the detailed explanation. However, you might want to remove the WHERE clause inside the CTE as you are already doing it in the sub-sequent statements.

Actually the WHERE clauses serve different purposes.
The one in the CTE is to count how many have checking accounts.
The one in the main query is to select individuals that have checking accounts that are from a household with several checking accounts. Subtle differences.

What you need is an EXISTS() condition:
SELECT *
FROM AccountsInfo A
WHERE A.AccountType = 'CHK'
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM AccountsInfo A2
    WHERE A2.Household_ID = A.Household_ID
    AND A2.AccountType = 'SAV'
)
ORDER BY A.Individual_ID

Results:



Individual_ID
Household_ID
AccountType




101
HH_101
CHK


103
HH_101
CHK


107
HH_104
CHK


110
HH_106
CHK



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This is a simpler approach. Like the simplicity.

I like both provided answers, but also I'm finding this combination of both to be useful as well:
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT
    Household_ID AS hid,
    COUNT(Individual_ID) AS num_indivs
  FROM AccountsInfo
  GROUP BY Household_ID
  HAVING COUNT(Individual_ID) > 1
)
  
SELECT
  Individual_ID,
  HouseHold_ID,
  AccountType
FROM AccountsInfo
WHERE AccountType = 'CHK'
AND HouseHold_ID IN ( SELECT hid from cte )

DB Fiddle link
Summary:

Get the aggregation "the households with the num of individuals more than 1"
Get the result filtering by both the aggregation and the account type


Agreed this is also a very good approach. Thanks for the answer.

The IN clause is straightforward but I always learned that JOINS would be more performant. I'm not sure that is still true these days though (and depending on the database). The nice thing about IN is its succinct and simple. Though the EXISTS clause also is simple. Benchmarking will tell which is better.
